# Como enviar información de una clase a otra en php

Tags: php, mvc

Vi un tutorial y completé todo, pero nunca me explicaron como pasar los parámetros de la url que se obtienen en una clase y los envía a la clase de otro controlador

Este es mi archivo **Core.php**

```html
<?php
class Core{
 protected $currentController = 'pages';
 protected $currentMethod = 'index';
 protected $parameters = [];

 public function __construct(){
  //0 Controller 1 Method > 2 Parameters print_r($this->getUrl());
  $url = $this->getUrl();
  //Check controllers
  if (file_exists("../app/controllers/" . ucwords($url[0]).".php")) {
   //Set controller as default
   $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
   unset($url[0]);
  }


  require_once "../app/controllers/".$this->currentController . ".php";
  $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

  //Check method
  if (isset($url[1])) {
   if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
   $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
   unset($url[1]);
      }
  }
  //echo $this->currentMethod;
  
  $this->parameters = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

  //Callback array parameters
  call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->parameters);
 }

 public function getUrl(){
  if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
   $url = rtrim($_GET["url"], '/');
   $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
   $url = explode("/", $url);
   return $url;

  }
 }
}
?>
```

Y este es mi **Demo.php**

```html
<?php
class Demo extends Controller{
 public function __construct(){
  #$this->articleModel = $this->model("Article");
  $this->userModel = $this->model("User");
  $this->orderModel = $this->model("Ticket");
 }
 public function index(){
  $users = $this->userModel->getSet();
  $data = [
   "users" => $users
  ];      
  $this->view("manager/home", $data);       
 }

 public function usuario(){
  echo($this->currentMethod());
 }

?>
```

Ahora, lo que llevo intentando es llamar al $this->parameters como lo especifica la función y no sirve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo espero te sirva

```
class A
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'Some Name';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function getNameOfA()
    {
        return $this->a->getName();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);

$b->getNameOfA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en tu ternario.

Tienes:

```
$this->parameters = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
```

debería ser:

```
$this->parameters == $url ? array_values($url) : [];
```

Aunq es muy raro lo que haces, porque estás comparando un array con lo que creo que es un string.

En base a lo que comentas en tu pregunta, te doy esto, pero no dices nada de que error te arroja o algo que nos ayude a identificar mejor que es lo que pasa. Decir "no sirve", no ayuda a que te ayudemos.

Si mejoras tu pregunta, mejoraré mi respuesta.

Comment: De hechono tengo ningun error, no me dice nada, sólo que la función $this->parameters no existe